# Can I transpose columns to rows in a SFDC report?

Tags: einstein-analytics, custom-reports, column

If I dont have Einstein Analytics, and I want to report on a single object, and transpose few columns into rows, with rest of the fields repeating, is this possible in another method in the Out-of-the-box reports tool in SFDC?

See Sample screenshots below 1, showing 3 attributes against each location that need to be transposed into rows in second image

[image: Sample data in report 1, showing 3 attributes against each location that need to be transposed into rows in second image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you would need Einstein Analytics licenses to transpose data from columns to rows.

Check similar example [here](https://www.simplysfdc.com/2019/09/einstein-analytics-transpose-multi.html).